# Menu responsive con flex box

Tags: responsive, jmenubar

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #bbb;
}

a {
  color: #000;
}


/* header */

.header {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  position: fixed;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 480px;
  z-index: 3;
}

.header ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.header li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header li a:hover,
.header .menu-btn:hover {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.logo {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.mail {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* menu */

.header .menu {
  text-align: center;
  clear: both;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height .2s ease-out;
}


/* menu icon */

.header .menu-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 28px 20px;
  position: relative;
  user-select: none;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">

  <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
  <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="nav-icon"></span></label>
  <a href="/" class="logo">LOGO</a>
  <a href="/" class="mail">MAIL</a>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">TEMA1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">TEMA2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#e">TEMA3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">TEMA4</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Hola estoy haciendo un menu responsive solo con CSS y HTML, he estado intentando de colocar tres elementos en linea: hamburguer-icon, logo y mail-icon, como puedo alinear los tres elementos de tal manera que el logo siempre este al centro sin importar el tamano de pantalla y los otros dos elementos a los costados, lo he intentado con flexbox. Supongo que debo de estar haciendo algo mal porque no he tenido exito alguno, si alguien tiene una respuesta o una guia lo agradeceria.

En la imagen numero dos se ve que los elementos estan uno debajo de otro, cuando deberian de estar uno al lado del otro.(menu-icon logo mail)

Comment: Puedes probar a poner float left al primero, float right al de la derecha y añadir el del centro de último y centrado

Comment: Al costado.... ¿cuál costado?

Comment: @Benito-B   Hola, gracias por la sugerencia, lo habia intentado con floats derecha para el menu hamburguesa e izquierda para el mail icon y centrado el logo, pero todo se rompe, lo intente con el flex box global y se rompe igual, ahora si lo hago con elementos individuales se colocan en columna y hasta este punto llegue.

Comment: @BetaM uno al costado del otro, Menu-icon Logo Mail-icon, ahora estan en columna.